# How to add a local project as a dependency to another project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have two projects that I am developing using Intellij IDEA and Gradle. Project A depends on project B, but I cannot get the dependency working.

After I add project B as a module of project A, Intellij tells me to add project B as a dependency, so I do that, but when I build it, it throws a circular dependency error.

How can I get project A to depend on project B?

Comment: Please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html.